# call objective c methods from javascript

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

i've implemented a simpleHttpServer and it's working perfectly. I have a index.html page which shows up on the client browser when they're connected to the server(iPhone). Is there a way to access objective-C methods from this index.html page.

Comment: through a browser, no. that would be a serious security flaw. through your own native application, yes, but then you'd already be able to run objective-c without the need of the server/javascript.

Comment: You might want to write at least a brief answer as a result of the resolved problem. @dqhendricks, you forgot to mention that it's somehow possible to do via standalone iOs application registered for custom url schemes :)